# WiFi not working after connect to WPA2 Enterprise in Android

Tags: android, wifi, enterprise

I am programmatically trying to configure our organization WiFi access point which requires the following settings,

```
Sec.Type  : WPA2-Enterprise 
Enc.Type  : AES 
Net.Auth.Method : PEAP
```

Also it requires the org Active Directory user name and password for authentication.

In iPhone I could easily able to configure this with the WPA2-Enterprise security type with AD user name and password.

But, in Android I could configured the same access point with the following details.

```
Security : 802.1x EAP.
EAP Method : PEAP
Phase 2 authentication : None.
CA Certificate : Unspecified.
user certificate : Unspecified.
Identity : ad user name.
password : ad password.
```

Once I configure the about network it authenticates and connects to the network with valid ip.

But, the trouble comes here, even after connecting to the network am not able to browse anything also not even able to ping laptops which all are connected in the same WiFi network.

Any pointers or suggestions needed.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, besides selecting MSCHAPv2 as phase 2, I had to write the identity field in the format of username@domain instead of the domain\username usually used in windows.

Answer (score 0):

With [PEAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protected_Extensible_Authentication_Protocol) you **have to choose** a phase 2. Usually [MSCHAPv2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protected_Extensible_Authentication_Protocol#PEAPv0_with_EAP-MSCHAPv2) is used.